# How to set printer black and white c# code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written a custom printer class.With  support color printer, I set PrintDocument..DefaultPageSettings.Color = false and  I also set  e.PageSettings.Color =false in PrintDocument_QueryPageSettings event. I have tested with Microsoft Print to PDF but output file has still color.Sorry my english.Thanks

Comment: It seems like this is a bug in .NET see this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ac77b0e-26d2-43ff-847b-6d8faf96b653/printer-settings-without-the-printdialog?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Yes .I see. Do you have any solution for this case? I don't want to use print dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have a solution for this , but i will suggest you to change printer settings to Black and white instead of setting this at document level

Comment: Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

I use Print Dialog in my printing code and I set the printing color like this:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

pd.PrintTicket.OutputColor = System.Printing.OutputColor.Monochrome;
```

But test it on a real printer